# paperclip: image not getting uploaded rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using paperclip gem in rails,

my user model file contains:

```
    has_attached_file :profile_pic, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" },
    default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png",
    :url  => "/assets/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

My image is not getting uploaded and hence not getting displayed (broken Image with "missing.png" appears).what should i do to upload my image to /assets/images path ?

and My view part look like:

```
<%= image_tag current_user.profile_pic.url(:thumb)  %>
```

Comment: Can you show the error you are getting in rails console

Comment: Started GET "/profile_pics/original/missing.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-04-01 10:45:36 +0530
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/profile_pics/original/missing.png"):

Comment: This is after image upload process and you are redirected to view page..I need to see logs when you start uploading

Comment: https://expirebox.com/download/4e46ccf77c5747cd6d53c65d02fe12a8.html

Answer (score 1):

It might be due to various reason

1) In strong parameter you need to define :profile_pic

2) you forgot to put missing.png

3):path =>:rails_root/public/assets/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

it might be wrong way to define path first :class then :style and then after :extension

:path => "images/:class/:style/:id.:extension"

Comment: Hi,

1.  :profile_pic mentioned in strong parameters

2.  missing.png is already there in assets/images

3.  tried this, but didn't help.

Comment: thank you, but the problem is solved, Imagebrick path was incorrect: This :
`Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"` 
should be
`Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/"`
my system.